# PHP : How to decode json string with quotes

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

A server returns a string like this:

```
string(150) ""\"{ 'success': false, 
'message': Email address already registered, 
'error': { 'code': 100, 
           'message': 'Email address already registered!' }}\"""
```

Calling **json_decode** on the result doesn't change the string into array, it just remains a string.

How can I fix this string to be converted to a PHP array?

Comment: If the original json string has quotes around it, it isn't valid json. It is a string. You could try to trim off the quotes and json_decode what is left.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ok, and I want to read the success and message part of the string. Will it be possible?

Comment: @Relm, of course, `preg_match` will do the job

Comment: even easier than preg_match, trim does have a parameter of characters you want to remove from the beginning/end of a string. `trim($jsonStr, '"\\');` would remove all `"` and `\ ` from the ends.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn, ok, could I be able to get the value of "success"?

Comment: well, developing an example real quick I noticed that this isn't even valid json as it stands. The value for `message` is missing quotes. json_decode won't decode invalid json so you would need to fix that first or parse it manually.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn cool, will appreciate that example.

Comment: it isn't valid json, I can't make an example. If the server responds with invalid json then you would have to parse it manually. The built in php functions won't do it for you.

Comment: That's absolutely not a valid json string.

Comment: what sort of server app returns a string like this?  This isnt a json string, it is a result of var_dump . Can you change the server codee

Comment: Nobody except you can access local host, it points to your machine from your machine. Show the code that generates the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still need to get values of `success` and `message` keys from that string - use the following approach with `preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$str = "\"{ 'success': false, 
'message': Email address already registered, 
'error': { 'code': 100, 
           'message': 'Email address already registered!' }}\"";

preg_match_all("/'(?<k>success|message)':(?<v>[^,]+)(?=,)/", $str, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches['k'], $matches['v']);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [success] =>  false
    [message] =>  Email address already registered
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.!!!

```
        $string = ""\"{ 'success': false, 
        'message': 'Email address already registered', 
        'error': { 'code': 100, 
                   'message': 'Email address already registered!' }}\""";

       $replace_hash_string =  str_replace("\","",$string);
       $final_string =  str_replace('"""','',$replace_hash_string);

       $converted_array = json_decode($final_string);

       echo "<pre>";
       print_r($converted_array);
       echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.!!!